# Python django 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'subject'

Tags: python, django

how do I write here because I do not know how to solve my problem, it turns out that I am creating an online test portal and I need to know that I am failing, I explain the context at the time of creating a question an evaluation index should be indicated, and this has a filter that agrees the subject and course of the test in question. Well the filter works shows me the indicators that are of a specific course and subject, but only when I enter a manual id instead when I pass the quiz variables it throws the error: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'subject 'I leave the form code and the view so they can tell me that I am failing please.

forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'questions'  
    fields = ('number','planificacion','text','description', 'puntaje' ,'image','document' )
    label = 'Pregunta'



def __init__(self ,quiz ,*args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['planificacion'].queryset = PlanificacionIndicador.objects.filter(planificacion__asignatura__id=quiz.subject.id, planificacion__curso__id=1)
```

As you can see in the filter I did the planning__course__id = 1 has an id set manually and the other has as I want, I must say that the filter works what fails is that at the time of wanting to save throws the error.

view.py

```
@login_required
@teacher_required
def question_add(request, pk):

quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=pk, owner=request.user)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)


    if form.is_valid():
        question = form.save(commit=False)
        question.quiz = quiz
        question.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Ahora puede agregar respuestas / opciones a la pregunta.')
        return redirect('teachers:question_change', quiz.pk, question.pk)
else:
    form = QuestionForm(quiz=quiz)
return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/question_add_form.html', {'quiz': quiz,'form': form})
```

this is the error

```
Internal Server Error: /teachers/quiz/79/question/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Oficina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\Oficina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\Oficina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Oficina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Oficina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Proyectos\proyecto-educa-quiz\classroom\views\teachers.py", line 
535, in question_add
form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
File "C:\Proyectos\proyecto-educa-quiz\classroom\forms.py", line 409, in 
__init__self.fields['planificacion'].queryset =
```

PlanificacionIndicador.objects.filter(planificacion__asignatura__id=quiz.subject 
    .id, planificacion__curso__id=1)
    AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'subject'

Comment: This is an English Website ! please translate from Spanish to English

Comment: Agree with @FabioSpaghetti that this should be translated or removed.  Not really speaking Spanish, I'm not sure of your actual question, but just in case it helps: the error is coming from the fact that you are passing `request.POST`, which is a [QueryDict object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) as the `quiz` argument to `QuestionForm.__init__`.  Perhaps it would be better to use a `kwarg` for `quiz`?

Comment: @RishiG 
And how can I do that?

Comment: Misread the code.  It's not a problem with kwargs, you just forgot the `quiz` arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put in the `quiz` arg to `QuestionForm.__init__` in the `POST` case.  That line should read

```py
    form = QuestionForm(quiz, request.POST, request.FILES)
```